# NLua - System DLL Not Found Exception

Tags: vb.net, lua, .net-4.5, nlua

Having a serious complication with trying to use Lua in VB.NET.  My question is How do I get this Library to load properly so that it is actually usable.

**Here are my attempts.**

1. I tried several variations of the Lua library via NuGet. And after some research, I found LuaInterface (not available in NuGet, and [the official repo references NLua](https://code.google.com/p/luainterface/) as it's successor).
2. Started a baby fresh project, referencing only NLua from NuGet.  -- fails
3. Added reference to Lua from NuGet -- still fails
4. Started a fresh project, and downloaded the current binaries directly from [github](https://github.com/NLua/NLua) for NLua --- fails.

In all of the above cases, I checked the build folder to ensure that all DLL's existed (as Visual Studio still doesn't deploy all dll's all the time -- see SQLite library for example of this).

**The error I am at now is this**

> A first chance exception of type 'System.DllNotFoundException'
>   occurred in KeraLua.dll

Now the BIG problem comes when I explicitly declare a reference to this file, as it creates a conflict since KeraLua.dll, and NLua.dll  BOTH have a "Lua" method with identical parameters.

**The code I am using where it crashes is pretty simple**:

```
Imports NLua

Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Dim l As New Lua


    End Sub
End Class
```

If someone could shed some light on why this library is failing so hard or what I may be doing wrong, it would be much appreciated.  I am currently trying to use this library to expose a table written in Lua inside a .net environment.  I have seen the examples on this on here, and they are dated as they reference the LuaInterface object which is deprecated.

Comment: Sanuel, do you know if is working using C#? KeraLua uses the native Lua52.dll (and you will need the vcredist 2013 installed to run the Lua52.dll).

Comment: I was able to get it to partially work using the "Pure C#" download, however when it has an exception, it just burps and terminates the process without any error. I am able to work around it, but it is still a pain in the butt to try and traverse a table structure.  Examples do not work, as I must call the value via the integer location, and if the result is another table, there doesn't seem to be a way to go up further, even creating a var of the type LuaTable causes an exception so forced to use "Object"